# MS ACCESS 2007: Limiting subform requery to specific tab

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

My database is utilizing a metrics dashboard I put together, where there's 5 comboboxes used for parameters to requery subforms in the tabs below it.  I have it so everything is functional, but with 5+ subforms based on multiple queries using those same paramters, performance is starting to take a hit.

How could I go about limiting the requery to the currently selected tab?

I can't currently paste my code, but it's basically consisting of a bunch of Me.[subform].Requery's where each query/subform references the same parameters across multiple tabs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which event(s) are you currently using to requery the subforms?

Comment: Sorry, but without code and a screenshot of the form this question is rather pointless. How are we supposed to know what's going on?

Comment: Truth is, your code is not worth to anyone :) please post your code stripping off your sensitive data if you want. for a blind answer, if you don't want to show all the sub-forms, just use navigation form which has on-demand load/query!

Comment: Sorry folks and I understand the downvotes - I was hoping it was simple enough to answer without posting code.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up finding the answer to my own question, thanks to all those who took the time to respond.  I ended up using SELECT Case code for the tab in the parameter combobox after updates.

```
Private Sub cboMonth_AfterUpdate()
  Select Case Me.TabCtrl.Pages(Me.TabCtrl).Name
  Case "Analysis"
       Me![sfrm_Analysis].Requery
  Case "Travel"
       Me![sfrm_Travel].Requery
  Case "Sharing"
       Me![sfrm_Sharing].Requery
  End Select
End Sub
```

...and so on for 3 different comboboxes and 2 text boxes (FY, Quarter, Month, Date-range),  I didn't post a screenshot because as one commenter suggested, it's sensitive and I'd have to recreate a dummy version on a separate PC just to show you all.  Anyway, thanks again for your responses.